# How many users can login on an extranet concurrently using the same username and password?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-accounts, login, extranet, concurrency

I got asked an interesting question regarding the a number of users using a generic login to sign in at the same time across different machines. 
Is there a particular number that Microsoft recommends given the evident performance hit the environment might eventually see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought it wouldn't be advisable to have multiple people using the same login, there isn't any limits specifically to the number of concurrent connections per username.  For capacity planning, treat each individual connection as unique when determining the number of users you need to support.  So, if 3000 people are using the same account, plan for 3000 connections in your capacity planning.

Comment: That's what I though too. However, isn't it easier to have just a single account with concurrent users rather than have individual accounts for each if they are to be setup with the same permission levels and need access to the same content on sharepoint?

Comment: For security reasons, no.  Reporting, auditing, removing access, etc., it's always best practice for each user to have their own account.  You can use SharePoint Audiences and SharePoint Groups to manage the permissions.

Comment: hmm you got a point..a couple actually. Besides these issues though, there aren't any limits on the number of concurrent users though, right?

Comment: Correct.  You just need the hardware to be able to handle it.

Comment: Also for licensing it's easier to say "look, I have 3,000 users so I bought 3,000 CALs" vs. having to explain to Microsoft how you can be sure 3,000 people are using that one account.